# webflux how to pass current login Mono string to a flux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

I am still new to Spring boot Webflux. I am using Casssandra as my database, below i have a friends tables, i want to get all my friends based on my login ID. How can i get the current login ID and pass the ID to a flux

```
// Here i retrieved currently login user ID which is a mono string

public Mono<String> getUserID(Mono<String> principal) {
  return principal
   .map(Principal::getName)
}
```

OR

```
public static Mono<String> getUserIDFromRequest(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.principal()
            .cast(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)
            .map(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::getName);
}

// My friends table

public class Friends {
  @PrimaryKey("userid")
  private long userId;
  private long friendId;
  private FriendObject friendObject;
  private String since;
  private boolean enableNotifications;
  private boolean allowMessages;
  // Getters and setters
}

@Repository
public interface FriendsRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<Friends, Long> {
}

@Service
public class FriendshipServiceImpl implements FriendshipService {
  @Override
  public Mono<Friends> addFriend(Friends friends) {
    return friendsRepository.save(friends);
  }
}

public class FriendshipHandler {

  // How to pass the Login Mono<String> to this flux Or how can i combine Mono and Flux?
  @GetMapping(path="/friends/list", produces=MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  Flux<Friends> getFriends(Mono<Principal> principal) {
    return friendshipService.getFriends(Long.valueOf("The login ID"));
  }

  OR

  public Mono<ServerResponse> getFriends(ServerRequest request) {
     return ok().body(
      friendshipService
        .getFriends(Long.valueOf("The login ID")), Friends.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: are you asking if you want to return a mono or a flux?

Comment: I want to return a flux but i need to pass login ID as argument

Comment: This is a question about how to dynamically use credentials with Spring-Data-Jpa, not a question about reactive services.

Comment: @K.Nicholas My question is about spring boot webflux using Cassandra as my database. You can also get the login user credentials from webflux

Answer (score 0):

this is basic webflux so if you can't do this you need to read up

```
@GetMapping(path="/friends", produces=MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
Flux<Friends> getFriends(Mono<Principal> principal) {
    return principal.map(principal -> {
        return // Here you do what you need to with the principal
    });
}
```

Comment: With this remember i am returning a flux.     return friendshipService.getFriends(Long.valueOf(principal.getName())); The Princlipal is a mono so i am getting an error which says Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<Object> to Flux<Friends>

Comment: @ChristianIbanibo, did you find any solution? I am finding the solution for the same issue.

Comment: if you need to convert a `Mono<T>` into a `Flux<T>` you can use the `flatMapMany` function.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read about [ReactiveSecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc-erms.html)